# Inverse transform failing due to non-broadcastable input operand

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am doing a  time-series forecasting.
The code runs well until the part:

```
y_pred_future = sc_predict.inverse_transform(predictions_future)
```

Error message:

```
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (60,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (60,52)
```

Here is a glimpse of what the data looks like:

`dataset_train`

```
month         total_sales  product_category_1 product_category_2 ...
2020-05-01        30.2              0                  1
```

`dataset_train.shape` -->> (13338, 54)

Code:

```
# Select features (columns) to be involved intro training and predictions
cols = list(dataset_train)[1:] #exclude the month column

#extract dates (will be used in visualization)
datelist_train = list(dataset_train['month'])
datelist_train = [dt.datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date() for date in datelist_train]

#DATA PREPROCESSING
dataset_train = dataset_train[cols].astype(str)
dataset_train = dataset_train.astype(float)

# Using multiple features (predictors)
training_set = dataset_train.values #convert to matrix

#START TRAINING
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-10, patience=10, verbose=1)
rlr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=10, verbose=1)
mcp = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights.h5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)

tb = TensorBoard('logs')

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, shuffle=True, epochs=30, callbacks=[es, rlr, mcp, tb], validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, batch_size=256)

#MAKE FUTURE PREDICTIONS
# Generate list of sequence of days for predictions
datelist_future = pd.date_range(datelist_train[-1], periods=n_future, freq='1d').tolist()


# Perform predictions
predictions_future = model.predict(X_train[-n_future:])

# Inverse the predictions to original measurements

y_pred_future = sc_predict.inverse_transform(predictions_future)
```

The solution proposed in [ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (3,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493559/valueerror-non-broadcastable-output-operand-with-shape-3-1-doesnt-match-the/47493938) does not seem to fit my problem.

Update: sample of `predictions_future[:5]`

```
array([[0.1624636 ],
       [0.36933464],
       [0.48372838],
       [0.61350775],
       [0.47355705]], dtype=float32)
```

Update: sample of `sc_predict.fit_transform(training_set[:, 1:])`

```
array([[-0.18426472, -0.04503773, -0.11018824, ..., -1.77882575,
        -0.1864286 , -0.10299353],
       [-0.18426472, -0.04503773, -0.11018824, ...,  0.56216861,
        -0.1864286 , -0.10299353],
       [-0.18426472, -0.04503773, -0.11018824, ..., -1.77882575,
        -0.1864286 , -0.10299353],
       ...,
       [-0.18426472, -0.04503773, -0.11018824, ..., -1.77882575,
        -0.1864286 , -0.10299353],
       [-0.18426472, -0.04503773, -0.11018824, ...,  0.56216861,
        -0.1864286 , -0.10299353],
       [-0.18426472, -0.04503773, -0.11018824, ...,  0.56216861,
        -0.1864286 , -0.10299353]])
```

Comment: Please post a sample of `predictions_future`. Notice also that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter - code here is supposed to be *minimal* (edited out).

Comment: thanks, please find the update above

Comment: OK, but we will also need the `sc_predict` transformation and a sample of the data used to fit it (this is where the issue is, the rest of the code is largely irrelevant to the error).

Comment: please find updated above